# Getting error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to make functions repository. I have created four files:

```
Function.hpp, Function.cpp, FunctionsRepository.hpp, FunctionsRepository.cpp
```

I want to keep `pointers` to functions in `vector` of pointers.

//FunctionsRepository.hpp

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONSREPOSITORY_HPP
#define FUNCTIONSREPOSITORY_HPP

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class FunctionsRepository {
    private:
        static vector<double *> pointerToFunctions;
    public:
        static void addFunction(double * wsk);

};

#endif
```

//FunctionRepository.cpp

```
#include "FunctionsRepository.hpp"
void FunctionsRepository::addFunction(double * wsk) {
    pointerToFunctions.push_back(wsk);
}
```

//Functions.hpp

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_HPP
#define FUNCTOINS_HPP

#include "FunctionsRepository.hpp"

int constFunction(int numberOfVehicles);
void linearFunction();
void stepFunction();

#endif
```

//Funcctions.cpp

```
#include "Functions.hpp"

double constFunction(double numberOfVehicles){
    return numberOfVehicles/2;
}

double (*funcConstant)(double) = constFunction;

//ERROR HERE
FunctionsRepository::addFunction(funcConstant);
```

I want to add new functions to program as easily as its possible and use it leater in other parts of program.

But I dont get it. Why i am getting this error. The `addFunction()` method is static, that means I can use it in other classes or parts of program. Vector is `static` to make sure that is the only one copy for whole program.

Comment: The `addFunction` function takes a `double*` as argument. You try to pass something of type `double(*)(double)`. That's not the same thing.

Comment: Also you can only call functions inside other functions. Also you don't need to create `funcConstant`, you can just use `constFunction` directly.

Comment: You're getting the error because code only belongs in functions. And [putting `using namespace std;` into a header file is an invitation to a world of hurt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

Use function wrapper. std::function can stores callable objects. So, your code will contain something like this:

```
class FunctionsRepository {
    private:
        // void() - function prototype
        static std::vector<std::function<void()>> pointerToFunctions;
    public:
        static void addFunction(std::function<void()> wsk)
        {
            pointerToFunctions.push_back(wsk);
        }
};
```

for more information consult official documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Answer (score 0):

I solved It. I received an error because I was calling the `FunctionsRepository::addFunction(funcConstant);` expression out of any scope. I just created new function to execute this command and thats all.